# Is it possible create an oval and colored boxed using fancybox?

Tags: fancybox

I would like my red box to be oval.
Here is my code :

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}      
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{psfrag}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

$$\ddot{x}+\colorbox{red!10}{$\frac{\omega_0}{Q}$}\dot{x}+\omega_0^2 x=0$$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you forced to use fancybox or do you accept solutions with other packages as well?

Comment: Why not using `tcolorbox`?

Comment: hi, I was having a look at this package documentation while you posted this. Right now, this is a bit too time consumming for what i wanna do. But will certainly use this package later to improve my handouts!

Comment: @JeanLallemand: Time consuming? `\tcbhighlight` isn't really time - consuming. By the way,`$$...$$` is deprecated for more than 20 years.

Comment: Actually I meant `\tcbhighmath`

Answer (score 1):

Here are two ways with `pstricks`.

Comments aside: the language option should be loaded with the document class, since `babel 3.9`, to ensure language-dependent packages be aware of the document main language. Also, you shouldn't use the `$$ ... $$` construction, which is plain TeX, always prefer `\[ ... \]`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper, french]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{psfrag}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf} %% to compile with pdflatex -shell-escape under TeX Live or MacTeX, pdflatex --enable-write18 under MiKTeX
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\[ \ddot{x}+\colorbox{red!10}{$\dfrac{\omega_0}{Q}$}\dot{x}+\omega_0^2 x=0 \]

\[ \ddot{x}+\raisebox{\dimexpr-0.5\height +0.25ex}{\psovalbox*[fillcolor = red!20]{$ \dfrac{\omega_0}{Q} $}}\dot{x}+\omega_0^2 x=0 \]

\[ \ddot{x}+\raisebox{\dimexpr-0.5\height +0.25ex}{\psframebox*[fillcolor = red!30, framearc =.6]{$ \dfrac{\omega_0}{Q} $}}\dot{x}+\omega_0^2 x=0 \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thx, actually this shrinks all fractions, so does the color box when I putt the whole equation in a color box, how can i fix this?

Comment: @JeanLallemand: You're right. As I focused on obtaining the coloured background, I forgot that in a box, maths are typeset in `text mode`. For the present case, using `\dfrac` will ne enough. For more complex formulæ, you can begin `$\displaystyle ... $`, or even set for the current group `\everypsbox{\displaystyle}`. I've fixed the code, and updated the picture.

Comment: perfect, thx for all those precisions ( I have used \dfrac once for an exponential ) . I am new here but already love this site.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Bernard's answer, with `\tcboxmath` from `tcolorbox`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper, french]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\tcbset{%
  highlightstyle/.style={enhanced,colback=red!40,boxsep=0pt,frame hidden}
}


\begin{document}

\[ \ddot{x}+\tcboxmath[highlightstyle,sharp corners]{\frac{\omega_0}{Q}}\dot{x}+\omega_0^2 x=0 \]

\[ \ddot{x}+\tcboxmath[highlightstyle,auto outer arc, arc=15pt]{\frac{\omega_0}{Q}}\dot{x}+\omega_0^2 x=0 \]

\[ \ddot{x}+\tcboxmath[highlightstyle,octogon arc,arc is angular]{\frac{\omega_0}{Q}}\dot{x}+\omega_0^2 x=0 \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting:  no correction is required for the vertical position of the box!

Comment: yes looks great, I hate to have my fractions shrunk (so do the students)

Comment: It is exactly what I wanted, i could create my commands and combine them, thx a lot !

Comment: @JeanLallemand: The correct way to say `thank you' is to accept the answer that fits most ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer what do you mean by that (remember i just started here) ?  That I should only click on "this answer is usefull" for the best answer ?

Comment: @JeanLallemand: Exactly